# Is this a roach or a beetle?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's a beetle due to the lines on it's back/rear but I'm not positive and if I'm wrong I need to take action quickly. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Have you tried searching for similar images or compared your insect with pictures of cockroaches? It is expected that you will <b>demonstrate</b> that you have done some research on your own before asking questions here — for example try: https://bugguide.net/.  For information on how to use this site, please check out the tour: biology.stackexchange.com/tour and then the help pages on how to ask questions on this site: biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks! 

Comment: Please add where and when the creature was found. This is expected for species-id questions.

Comment: @tyersome The OPs insect is not an Anobiidae, as your comment suggests. For one, the pronotum and head angle is completely off.

Comment: @fileunderwater: Great I learned something!

Answer (score 5):

This is a [click beetle (Elateridae)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_beetle), so not a cockroach. This is most easily seen by the long pointed corners/angles at the posterior part of the pronotum, which is part of the “click” mechanism they use to flip themselves when they land of their back, or to startle predators.